# how to add my application settings to the settings on my phone in android?

Tags: android

The question is pretty much self explanatory. Here is a bit more a detail.
I have a application in which i have a language selection preferences screen. I screen is available only when my user starts the application.
I want my application to be listed on the Android Phone settings. From there the user, when clicks on the application icon, a preference or any screen is available from where the user can select the language he wants and then when he starts my application, the application automatically opens in that language.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without modifying the `Settings.apk` in `/system/app/` which would require root access.  A few custom ROMS have made changes similar to this (i.e. Cyanogenmod), but you should keep your application's settings within your application alone.